# Inequality involving $X_{(n)}$

Tags: probability-theory, order-statistics

I am trying to prove that for random variables (not necessarily iid) $X_1,...,X_n$ that $X_{(n)} \le x + \sum_{i=1}^n  X_i \mathbb{I}_{X_i > x}$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$.

I tried to show this by a contraction, which would lead to the assumption that:

$$
E (X_{(n)}) \overset{\text{assumed}}{>} x +\sum_{i=1}^n E[ X_i \mathbb{I}_{X_i > x}] \overset{\text{Markov Inequality}}{\ge} x+\sum_{i=1}^n  E[X_i]
$$

but I keep going around in circles, and since the rvs are not iid, it is confusing to work with the maximum, any hints?

**update** the inequality will only hold if $X_i$'s are assumed to be non-negative and $x \ge 0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true if the $X_i$ can be negative :

take $n=1$, $x=-2$ and $X_1 = -1$. Then

$$x+ X_{1}\Bbb 1_{X_{1}>x}= -2+(-1) = -3 < -2 = X_{(1)}$$

It is also not true if $x$ can be negative :

take $n=1$, $x=-1$ and $X_1 = 1$ Then

$$x+ X_{1}\Bbb 1_{X_{1}>x}= -1+1 = 0 < 1 = X_{(1)}$$

Now, if all the $X_i$ are positive, and that $x\geq 0$, you have

$$\forall \omega, X_{(n)}(\omega) = X_{(n)}(\omega) \Bbb 1_{X_{(n)} \leq x} (\omega) + X_{(n)} \Bbb 1_{X_{(n)} > x} (\omega) \leq x +  X_{(n)} \Bbb 1_{X_{(n)} > x} (\omega)$$

But $\forall \omega, \exists i, X_{(n)} (\omega) = X_i(\omega)$, so

$$ \forall \omega, X_{(n)} (\omega) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n X_i(\omega)$$

And you also have $$ \Bbb 1_{X_{(n)} > x} \leq \Bbb 1_{X_{i} > x} $$

So

$$ \forall \Bbb 1_{X_{(n)} > x}(\omega) X_{(n)} (\omega) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n X_i(\omega)1_{X_{(n)} > x}(\omega) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n X_i(\omega)1_{X_{i} > x}(\omega) $$

Hence the result
$$X_{(n)} \leq  x+ \sum_{i=1}^n X_i(\omega)1_{X_{i} > x}(\omega) $$

Comment: The question was stated like this, so I guess the question meant to prove it if the Xs were non negative, then I will try to prove the statement in that case

Comment: @dimebucker91 : it's also false if $x$ can be negative even if the $X_i$ are positive. Take $n=1$, $X_1 = 1$ and $x=-2$.

Comment: thanks, I updated the question accordingly

Answer (score 2):

For $x \in \mathbb{R}_+$

\begin{align}
\max_{1\le i\le n}\{|X_i|\}&=\max_{1\le i\le n}\{|X_i|1\{|X_i|\le x\}+|X_i|1\{|X_i|> x\}\} \\[1.7ex]
&\le \max_{1\le i\le n}\{x+|X_i|1\{|X_i|> x\}\} \\
&=x+\max_{1\le i\le n}\{|X_i|1\{|X_i|> x\}\} \le x+\sum_{i=1}^n |X_i|1\{|X_i|> x\}.
\end{align}

---

If $X_i\ge 0, i=1,\dots,n$, then $X_i=|X_i|$ and

$$\max_{1\le i\le n}\{X_i\}\le x+\sum_{i=1}^n X_i1\{X_i> x\}$$.

Comment: Why do we need the absolute values if we're assuming that the rvs are non negative?

Comment: @dimebucker91: I noticed your update after I posted this (so I left $|\cdot|$)... If $X$-s are non-negative then absolute values are redundant, of course.